# Sub command line after typing \ or ` in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, sh

What is the sub input terminal that shows up when I type the character \ or ` (backtick) into a Linux command line? It shows up with what I assume is a prompt that contains a single ">" character. (see image below)

It almost appears to be a scripting terminal (like python's ">>>").

[image]

I tried asking google but the question is hard to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just waiting for a closing backtick.

You can get the output from a commando using those backticks and assign it to a variable. If you would do `` myvar=`ls` ``, then the output of ls would be assigned to myvar.

You can use `myvar=$(ls)` likewise, and some suggest it is even more modern.

The case for the `\` is a bit different. The backslash allows to escape the meaning of the next character. When you "end" the line normally the command is excecuted, but not when the line ending is escaped. This can come in handy when writing shell scripts and you would like to spread long commands over multiple line.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping I was going to learn a new super power for the command line :/

Comment: @javey: Inserting arbitrary line breaks isn't a superpower?

Comment: "Some suggest"? There's no question in the historical record; the `$()` syntax was introduced into POSIX sh long after Bourne implemented literal backtick support (and for very good reason: Literal backticks are hard to nest, and the syntax needed for quoting around them is surprising and difficult to use).

Comment: @Charles Then why did the bourne shell introduce the two backticks? Just to save some typing?

Comment: You've got the history backwards. POSIX sh was introduced in the early 90s (with heavy influence from ksh). Bourne came out in the 1970s.

Comment: ...incidentally, David Korn is on the record saying he wishes that he'd gotten rid of backtick support altogether; see question #7 at https://news.slashdot.org/story/01/02/06/2030205/david-korn-tells-all

Answer (score 2):

This prompt is PS2 (just as your standard shell prompt is defined by the variable `PS1`). From [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html):

> `PS2` -- Each time the user enters a `<newline>` prior to completing a command line in an interactive shell, the value of this variable shall be subjected to parameter expansion and written to standard error. The default value is `"> "`. This volume of POSIX.1-2008 specifies the effects of the variable only for systems supporting the User Portability Utilities option.

---

Thus, this being printed means you've entered an incomplete command line at an interactive shell. You'd have the same thing if you had other kinds of quotes not completed, or an `if` statement without a closing `fi`.

Comment: Thanks for the POSIX standard quote. I can now export PS2 to something like "close your dang ` $" so I remember what this prompt means.

Comment: @javey You'll also get it after `(`, `while`, `if`, `\ `, `"` and a menagerie of other keywords and characters.

Answer (score 0):

It's just expect you to continue the previous command since the `newline` (press `Enter` key) doesn't close it.